# How to allow multiple images to be uploaded into webview android both from gallery and camera

Tags: android, webview, image-uploading, android-camera-intent

Hello so i've searched a lot for this and haven't figured it out. I am able to upload a single image using this code and push the image into the server. But the problem is its not allowing multiple image selection from gallery or when I click a picture it replaces the previous image and the 2nd image doesn't show up.

I have the entire code below could someone please suggest what I might have missed.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

WebView mWebView;

private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
String tag = "alarm_set_flag";
private Boolean alarm_set_flag;
SharedPreferences mPrefs;

private static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
private String mCameraPhotoPath;

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == 
null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }
        Uri[] results = null;
        // Check that the response is a good one
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data == null) {
                // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                }
            } else {
                String dataString = data.getDataString();
                if (dataString != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                }
            }
        }
        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
        mFilePathCallback = null;
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE || mUploadMessage == null) 
    {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
            if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                return;
            }
            Uri result = null;
            try {
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                    result = null;
                } else {
                    // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is 
null
                    result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : 
      data.getData();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }
    return;
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );
    return imageFile;
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // This is for the JS Interface
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebViewJavaScriptInterface(this), "app");

    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(false);
    mWebView.loadUrl("my url");
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
    }, 0);

    mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(tag,0);
    alarm_set_flag = mPrefs.getBoolean(tag,false);

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    });


    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
        }

        // For Android 5.0
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
            if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mFilePathCallback = filePath;
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                }
                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                            Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                } else {
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }
            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");
            Intent[] intentArray;
            if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            } else {
                intentArray = new Intent[0];
            }
            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,true);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
            return true;
        }
        // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
            // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
            File imageStorageDir = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                    , "AndroidExampleFolder");
            if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
            }
            // Create camera captured image file path and name
            File file = new File(
                    imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                            + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            + ".jpg");
            mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);
            // Camera capture image intent
            final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            // Create file chooser intent
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");
            // Set camera intent to file chooser
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                    , new Parcelable[] { captureIntent });
            // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }
        // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
        }
        //openFileChooser for other Android versions
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                                    String acceptType,
                                    String capture) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
        }

    });

    mWebView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    mWebView.setLongClickable(false);

}
public class WebViewJavaScriptInterface{

    private Context context;

    /*
     * Need a reference to the context in order to sent a post message
     */
    public WebViewJavaScriptInterface(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    /*
     * This method can be called from Android. @JavascriptInterface
     * required after SDK version 17.
     */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void jsBridge(int mints, int hrs, int ampm, int checkbox){
        int Min = mints;
        int Hours = hrs;
        int AMPM = ampm;
        int Checkbox = checkbox;

        if(Checkbox == 1){
            if(alarm_set_flag == true){
                cancelDailyNotification();
                setNotification(Hours,Min,AMPM);
                SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
                mEditor.putBoolean(tag, true).commit();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Daily Notification has been set.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                setNotification(Hours,Min,AMPM);
                SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
                mEditor.putBoolean(tag, true).commit();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Daily Notification has been set.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }else {
            if(alarm_set_flag == true){
                cancelDailyNotification();
                SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
                mEditor.putBoolean(tag, false).commit();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Daily Notification has been turned off.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                cancelDailyNotification();
                SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
                mEditor.putBoolean(tag, false).commit();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Daily Notification is already turned off.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }
}
public void setNotification(int hour, int minutes, int ampm){

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    if(ampm == 1) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    }else{
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
    }
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, notificationReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,pendingIntent);
}
public void cancelDailyNotification(){
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            notificationReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            getApplicationContext(), 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
    mEditor.putBoolean(tag, false).commit();
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event){
    String webUrl = mWebView.getUrl();

    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch(keyCode){
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if(mWebView.canGoBack()){
                    if((webUrl.contains("url"))){
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("title")
                                .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit the app?")
                                .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                }).setNegativeButton("no", null).show();
                    }
                    else
                    if((webUrl.contains("url"))){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Press the X button.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    if((webUrl.contains("url")||(webUrl.contains("file:///android_asset/error_page.html")||webUrl.contains("url")))) {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("title")
                                .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit the app?")
                                .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                }).setNegativeButton("no", null).show();
                    }else {
                        mWebView.goBack();
                    }
                }else {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("title")
                            .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit the app?")
                            .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }).setNegativeButton("no", null).show();
                }
                return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Try this code in `OnActivityResult`:

```
if (intent.getDataString() != null) {
    results = new Uri[] {
        Uri.parse(intent.getDataString())
    };
} else {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        if (intent.getClipData() != null) {
            final int numSelectedFiles = intent.getClipData().getItemCount();
            results = new Uri[numSelectedFiles];
            for (int i = 0; i < numSelectedFiles; i++) {
                results[i] = intent.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying this on Android older than 5.0, it won't work. Your `openFileChooser()` should also have:

```
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,true);
```

To allow multiple files selection.